# Pattern in a Numpy Series

Tags: arrays, numpy, pattern-matching

I have a Python Numpy array:

```
a = np.array([1,0,5,6,0,1,2,5,0,1,2,8,0,0,0,0,1,1,2,3,0,0,10,0])
```

I am trying to find the following:

a) Between each zero, return any sequential set of numbers where sum is equal or greater than 10

```
5,6
1,2,8
10
```

b) Between every set of sequential 5 numbers, return sequential set of numbers where sum is equal or greater than 10

```
1,0,5,6,0
0,5,6,0,1
5,6,0,1,2
6,0,1,2,5
2,5,0,1,2
5,0,1,2,8
0,1,2,8,0
1,2,8,0,0
2,8,0,0,0
2,3,0,0,10
3,0,0,10,0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take slices inside a list comprehension to do this.

```
idxs = np.where(a==0)[0]
group1 = [a[idxs[i-1]+1:idxs[i]] for i in range(1,len(idxs)) if a[idxs[i-1]+1:idxs[i]].sum()>=10]
group2 = [a[i:i+5] for i in range(len(a)-4) if a[i:i+5].sum()>=10]
```